# SCORM 1.2 the correct way to terminate the connection?

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2, lms

I'm writing a module designed to be used on Scorm 1.2. In my Javascript, when I call `LMSFinish("")`, the module exits, the window closes and everything seems to work.

However, when I investigate the debug logs for the LMS (I'm using Scorm Cloud) I get the error:

```
No API Runtime Nav Request, exit action=exit,no confirmation
```

Does anyone know what this means? I'm combing through whatever docs and examples I can find, sure seems like calling `LMSFinish("")` is the way to terminate the connection, not sure why I'm getting an error reported.

Comment: Are you setting the cmi.core.exit property before you call LMSFinish? If not, what happens if you do? Valid values are “time-out”, “suspend”, “logout”, “”. Search for 'cmi.exit' on this page for more info: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/

Comment: Oh yes. I'm setting cmi.core.exit to "suspend"